# Rails 4: No double items in shopping app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

building a shopping app but i don't want to show to listings of the same thing twice. I don't want it to show two listings for oranges. Instead I want it to show the quantity as 2.

I have changed the order_items_controller to show

```
@order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
    @order_item.quantity += 1
```

get error undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass

```
tr>
        <th>Order Total</th>
        <td><%= print_price @order.total %></td> <- error 
    </tr>

    <tr>
```

order_items.controller

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :load_order, only: [:create]


  # GET /order_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /order_items
  # POST /order_items.json
  def create
       @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])



    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Successfully Added Product To Cart.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /order_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /order_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.update(order_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order_item, notice: 'Order item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /order_items/1
  # DELETE /order_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @order_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @order_item.order }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order_item
      @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def load_order
        @order = Order.find_or_initialize_by_id(session[:order_id], status: "Unsubmitted")
        if @order.new_record?
          @order.save!
          session[:order_id] = @order.id
      end
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_item_params
      params.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :order_id, :quantity)
    end
end
```

orders.show.html

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :load_order, only: [:create]


  # GET /order_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /order_items
  # POST /order_items.json
  def create
       @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])



    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Successfully Added Product To Cart.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /order_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /order_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.update(order_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order_item, notice: 'Order item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /order_items/1
  # DELETE /order_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @order_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @order_item.order }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order_item
      @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def load_order
        @order = Order.find_or_initialize_by_id(session[:order_id], status: "Unsubmitted")
        if @order.new_record?
          @order.save!
          session[:order_id] = @order.id
      end
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_item_params
      params.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :order_id, :quantity)
    end
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy

    def total
        order_items.map(&:subtotal).sum
    end

end
```

order_items.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  validates :order_id, :product_id, presence: true

  def subtotal
    quantity * product.price
  end
end
```

I have also created a table to add quantity

```
class AddDefaultQuantityToOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :order_items, :quantity, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you should handle that not in the cart display part but when you add a product in your cart: If your cart already has the exact same product, increment the quantity.

Comment: The error you're getting "get error undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass" tells me that  the @order instance variable is not being set correctly when you call print_price here <%= print_price @order.total %>. Which controller action is leading to that view?

Comment: Do you have a link to this project on GitHub?

Comment: yes sure here you Doug Steinberg @https://github.com/neilp666/sincuruapp

Comment: hi @Doug Steinberg i think its the order_items controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in your order model. You need 'self' to reference the current Order object. Change it to this

```
def total
    self.order_items.map(&:subtotal).sum
end
```

Comment: Thanks Doug , really wierd one , got home it started working- didnt get any error message  but wasn't showing the totals added the self now it does

Comment: still havent worked how to stop doing the double orders though!

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, but I am noticing some of your code looks wrong. In the OrderItem class you have a subtotal method with this in it `quantity * product.price` I don't see where quantity or product is being passed into that method.

Answer (score 1):

In your create action for the order controller you need

```
@order = Order.find(<however you get the order id>)
```

you are trying to call a method on @order but you are not passing a value in the controller for that item as far as I can tell

Comment: @ruby_newbe -  He has a before action that creates the "@order" variable form the load_order method.